# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urls'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, web

Python 2.7 & Django 1.10
ERROR:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urls'
```

**main/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
import article

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(article.urls))

]
```

**article/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.basic_one, name='basic_one')
]
```

Structure:

APP/main/urls.py

APP/article/urls.py

Comment: Please show us your directory structure. Most probably, you will either need to change the import path or use `sys.path.append()`.

Comment: Please, don't write in Russian. Otherwise go here http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: ok! i am translate that!

Comment: Did you include the `__init__.py` file in the `article` directory? It's required for the directory to be treated as a module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In main/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from article import urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(urls))

]
```

Or

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('article.urls'))

]
```

You can learn more from [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to put just quotes around the includes and don't import articles. Like so:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('article.urls'))
]
```