# django Error: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error in Django. I saw a lot of similar questions but am not able to find a working solution. I think the error is in importing the User model. I am not able to find a solution to this. Basically, it seems that it is not able to get the User model. Please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\Python\TheRandomSite\investor\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import urls
  File "E:\Python\TheRandomSite\investor\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "E:\Python\TheRandomSite\investor\views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from investor.models import Game
  File "E:\Python\TheRandomSite\investor\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 105, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 237, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Kindly post the contents of your `investor/__init__.py` file.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil It only contains `from . import urls` which is needed in the `urls.py` of the main `urls.py` as an `include()`.

Comment: But why do you have to include it in the `__init__.py`? Why not explicitly import `urls` wherever necessary?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil As it gives this error otherwise `File "E:\Python\TheRandomSite\TheRandomSite\urls.py", line 28, in <module>
    url(r'^investor/', include(investor.urls)),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urls'
`

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625054/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-urls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Make `investor/__init__.py` as empty, Then

```
include('investor.urls')
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't know you could use a string. Thanks.