# Class has no atribute 'urls' - Django models.ImageField() can't migrate

Tags: python, django

I try to add ImageField but I get error.

**Code I am working with:**

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError 
import datetime


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  primary_key=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)  


class ProfileImages(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField()


#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

class ProfileImagesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProfileImages
    extra = 3

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ ProfileImagesInline, ]

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileImages)
```

This throws:
'Attribute Error' ProfileImages has no attrbute 'urls'. I don't know why. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the error when you run migrate, or makemigrations? Have you double-checked that you saved the file before running the command?

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625054/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-urls) out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter to `admin.site.register` is the ModelAdmin class. You are passing a model there instead.

```
admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```